# Is there a way to make this kind of circular/radial list view builder to measure weight?

Tags: flutter, dart

[image]

I tried various methods to achieve this design, but none of them were effective.

How can I create a circular/radial design that functions like a ListView.builder, allowing the user to slide and update a weight variable?

Comment: https://gist.github.com/pskink/5fd59d240beb8dd9d780f978e5c76b3c#file-sized_content_scrollable-dart-L113 - you have to modify it a bit so that the lines are drawn in arc shape and not linearly

Comment: I have linear one , but  struggle here for arc shape